# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'ParameterizedThreadStart'

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to create a new thread using a method from another cs file however I'm getting this error.

Here is the code

Program.cs:

```
using HangManSharp;
Backend _backend = new Backend();

Thread initThread = new Thread(_backend.getWord); //Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'ParameterizedThreadStart'
```

Backend.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HangManSharp
{
    internal class Backend
    {
        public string getWord()
        {
            const int wordCount = 50000;
            int randomWordNum = Random.Shared.Next(wordCount);
            try
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("words");

                for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++)
                {
                    sr.ReadLine();
                    if (i == randomWordNum)
                    {
                        return sr.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use multithreading because I want to display a loading screen while it gets the word.

I've tried putting everything in the same file and it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your method signature should match the delegate you're trying to use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart?view=net-6.0

Comment: Do try this `public string GetWord() => File.ReadLines("words").Skip(Random.Shared.Next(50000)).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();`.

Comment: And this works to call the method: `Thread initThread = new Thread(() => GetWord());`

Comment: I did change your method name to use the C# naming standard.

Comment: Why don't you use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` instead?